# how to create a key with auto increment of int and variable in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need to use auto increment for a key, starting from A001. Once it reaches A999, it should increment to B001. Is that possible?

Comment: Open this [Probably duplicate this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366122/mysql-custom-auto-generated-key-auto-increment-multiple-column-index) should help.

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` cannot do that without some extra work on your part.  Suggest you rethink your numbering scheme.